# Are questions about which is the license of a particular software on-topic?

Tags: support, licensing

I'd like to make a question about which is the corresponding license of a software who looks like open source software (its source code is accesible) but I cannot determine which exact license corresponds to it as I'm unable to find it, or even if it is a software without any type of license in that case I'd even be able to copy and modify it without any legal issue.

Are those type of questions on-topic here? If not, is there some other stackexchange page where this could be asked?